# ggplot2 change color of line based on categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to have one consistent line across a date range that changes colors based on a categorical variable.

Let's say the data looks like this:

Date    Value  Category 
1/1/14 - 10 - A 
1/2/14 - 11 - A
1/3/14 - 20 - B
1/4/14 - 26 - B
1/5/14 - 50 - D

I would like the line to change colors as it passes through the different categories. Is there a way to do this with ggplot2? Or will I need to use a different library.

I can get the line graph, but it is broken and disjointed. 
[image]

**Update**
Currently I can get a scatterplot to do what I want with

```
qplot(x=data1$date, y = data1$value,data = data1, color = data1$category,geom="point")
```

However when I use "line" it tells me that

> Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: Does this work for you `ggplot(df , aes(Date , Value , colour=Category , group=1)) +  geom_line()
`

Comment: user20650, your answer is appropriate, you shoudl submit as an answer so Alex can accept

Comment: I didn't think lines could be multicoloured in ggplot (hence my now-deleted comment) but I was wrong. @user20650 is right.

Comment: Given @user20650 's comment I now get "Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems" Admittedly I gave a made up sample set due to the privacy of the data

Comment: @Alex; you can also do this using qplot, but you need to use the group statement. `qplot(x=Date, y = Value,data = df, color = Category,group=1,geom="line")`.

Comment: @user20650 That was perfect and did EXACTLY what I wanted. Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign a group variable:

using qplot:

```
  qplot(x=Date, y = Value,data = df, color = Category,group=1,geom="line")
```

or ggplot:

```
ggplot(df , aes(Date , Value , colour=Category , group=1)) + geom_line()
```

Also note, in your qplot statement you do not need to use 'yourdata$' as you define the data = yourdata. If you use yourdata$var you will have problems using ggplot.